# Can neural networks used in time series data using R software?

Tags: r, time-series, neural-networks, forecasting

Can neural networks used in time series data using R software?

What are appropriate packages?

Do you have example codes?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Tensorflow package from RStudio.

https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/

Any numerical data can be consumed by a neural network and time series data is no exception.

Answer (score 1):

The `nnetar()` function in the `forecast` package will fit an extremely simple feed-forward neural network with a single hidden layer. It does not even automatically include seasonal lags for seasonal time series.

Of course, you can use "general" neural network packages and feed in time series with appropriate lags.

Comment: Are you sure that nnetar uses RNN? I think it uses feed forward NNets.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/341397/how-does-neural-network-auto-regression-produce-multistep-forecasts

Comment: @Alex: thanks! You are right, I misremembered. Edited it into the answer.