# How to fit trainted model on test dataset in arfima() implementation

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I am using arfima function (arfima package 1.6-8 version) for forecasting the future requests workload on the server. I split my dataset into training and test datasets. I trained my model on training dataset for forecasting future requests values. Now, i want to fit this model on test dataset. I didn't find any method for this purpose in the arfima package document. I request you to provides information about how can i fit the trainted model on test data set.

Thanking You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For models like ARIMA and ARFIMA, you don't fit a model to test data. 
You fit a model to the training (i.e. past) data, then you use the resulting model to generate forecasts into the future. This is called [recursive forecasting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/346196/89649). 
Then you evaluate the forecasts against your test data using various accuracy metrics.

In the arfima package, forecasting is performed using using the predict function:

```
fit <- arfima(data, order = c(0, 1, 1), back=T)
pred <- predict(fit, n.ahead = 5)
```

Comment: Thanks, how could we save the fitted model parameters for forecasting in a dynamic environment?

Comment: @SatishKumar you could save the parameters (they are all stored as R variables) however in a dynamic environment, you are likely going to want to refit your model everytime, since the best fitting model will change depending on the new data coming in. See [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/3-facts-about-time-series-forecasting-that-surprise-experienced-machine-learning-practitioners-69c18ee89387)